# Paginação de imagens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estou precisando listar algumas imagens, que precisam ser mostradas em grupos de 6 por página. Pode ser qualquer tipo de paginação.

Eu tenho conhecimentos em Banco de Dados, PHP, consigo trazer as imagens do banco, porém estou a procura de uma paginação simples, que posso usar em qualquer projeto, p. ex.:

```
<- 1 2 3 .. ->
```

Conheço o `limit` do HTML, mas ai ele so vai limitar o quanto vai ser visto, eu precisava que mostrasse todos os itens do banco, mas com paginação, conheçem algum plug-in?

Comment: Meu caro, o ideal é que você mostre algo que já tenha produzido... Somos uma comunidade que soluciona dúvidas, mas você precisa partir de algum lugar...

Comment: E onde está a lista de imagens? No HTML? No PHP vinda de um BD? No JavaScript?

Comment: Olá, eu tenho conhecimentos em Banco de dados, php, consigo trazer as imagens do banco, porem estou a procura de uma paginacao simples, que posso usar em qualquer projeto...

ex:

<- 1 2 3 .. ->

Comment: Você conhece a cláusula `LIMIT` do MySQL? Usá-la seria a maneira mais básica de implementar paginação.

Comment: @bfavaretto quanto de mais "baixo nível" a paginação, melhor (creio). O ideal seria usar o LIMIT, **aliado a uma boa definição de índices na base de dados**.

Comment: eu conheço o limit do html, mas ai ele so vai limitar o quanto vai ser visto, eu precisava q mostrasse todos os itens do banco, mas com paginação, conheçem algum plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta ficou muito genérica e no final eu entendi que serve qualquer tipo de paginação em PHP que trabalhe com imagens. Pesquisando, encontrei [este link](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/308498-resolvidopaginao-para-galeria-de-fotos-e-muito-mais/) que possui um snippet implementando o que você deseja:

```
<?php
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456") or die(mysql_error());//Link de conexão com banco
mysql_select_db("bd_galeria") or die(mysql_error());//seleção do banco
$num_por_pagina = 20; // numero de imagens (registros) por página
$pagina = !$_GET["pagina"] ? 1 : $_GET["pagina"]; // Caso não haja numeração, torna-se página 1
$primeiro_registro = ($pagina*$num_por_pagina) - $num_por_pagina;
//o calculo acima é para saber qual o primeiro registro q deve aparecer nesta página
// Ex: primeiro = 2 x 20 = 40; 40 - 20 = 20 - > 20 é o primeiro registro da página 2 levando em consideração que 0 é o primeiro da página 1
$pesquisa = "select * from images order by id desc limit $primeiro_registro, $num_por_pagina";
// string de pesquisa mysql simles determinando em limit qual o primeiro registro e até onde vai além desse primeiro
$busca_fotos = mysql_query($pesquisa, $conexao); // executa a consulta
list($total_fotos) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(*) from images", $conexao));// conta quantos registros há na tabela
$total_paginas = $total_fotos/$num_por_pagina; // calcula o numero de páginas necessárias de acordo com o numero de fotos pra cada uma
$prev = $pagina - 1; // página anterior
$next = $pagina + 1; // próxima página
$total_paginas = ceil($total_paginas); // pega o inteiro do numero de páginas
$to_linha = 1; // variavel de controle para informação de qual coluna na tabela estamos
$painel = "<table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tr>"; // começa a tabela com a paginação
for ($x=1; $x<=$total_paginas; $x++){
    if ($x==$pagina) { // Se a página for a atual não vai ter link
        $painel .= "<td align=\"center\" valign=\"middle\" width=\"27\">$x</td>";
    } else {// caso contrario tem link
        $painel .= "<td align=\"center\" valign=\"middle\" width=\"27\"><a href=\"$PHP_SELF?pagina=$x\">$x</a></td>";
    }
    if($to_linha == 15){ // 15 é o numero de colunas que você quer na tabela caso tenha muita paginação, assim ele colocaria o 16 na linha de baixo não deixando q seu layout tenha 2 metros de largura
        $painel .= "</tr><tr>";// fecha linha e abre outra
        $to_linha = 1;// já que mudou de linha, reinicia o controle de colunas
    }
    $to_linha++; // add 1 as colunas
}
$painel .= "</tr></table>";// após o término fecha a tabela que fica guardada na variavel $painel que você pode colocar onde quiser que a páginação apareça
?>
```

**Insta salientar** que, devido à natureza do fonte e sua idade (2008), podem ser necessárias adaptações em funções específicas, mas é o melhor a fazer diante do aspecto generalista da pergunta.